# Waiting for localhost

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows-7

When I visit "localhost:3000", my browser says "Waiting for localhost..." and never returns.

Here is what the log shows:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Sep 03 10:47:33 -0400 2012
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

My database.yml content:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: chairsales_development
  username: root
  password: scrubbed
  host: localhost
```

I can connect fine to MySql 5.5 from the command line using this user/password.
I have tried adding port 3306 to the config yml file with no change in results.

The routes.rb file contains only this map line:

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

How can I further diagnose this and get more information about what is happening? Is there a way to get more verbose results in the log from rails itself?

Windows 7 + MySQL 5.5 + Rails 3.2.8

Contents of my.ini file in MySQL root dir:

```
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K
```

Comment: What happens if you run `rails db`?

Comment: I get a prompt for password. After entering the password used in database.yml, I am logged in and see the mysql command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and have a look if the server binds to an ip address or a socket or both. When it binds to a socket use the socket to bind to the server instead of using the network. You can do this by passing the `socket /path/to/socket` instead of the `host` parameter.

Comment: I don't seem to have a "my.cnf" file anywhere. Running MySql 5.5 on Windows 7 with Rails 3.2.8

Comment: ohh my god you should hav mentioned that,... Then you can use sockets because there are no sockets in wndows systems. Have a look at the programms folder of mysql. there you will find the my.cnf. Then replace the `host localhost` with `host <bindaddress of mysql server>`

Comment: Found several version of INI fils (my-large.ini, etc.). Used the "small" version to create a "my.ini" in the MySQL root dir.

Comment: Contents of my.ini:[client]
#password = your_password
port  = 3306
socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port  = 3306
socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K

Comment: STILL NEED HELP - how can I cut this problem in half - find more detail about what is really happening?

Comment: open a cmd and try `telnet localhost 3306` which should work if the mysqld is bound to the loopback. If it doesnt work try the same with your ip address instead of localhost.